# neo4j 3.2.2-1 constant restart just after Failed to find a usable hardware address

Tags: neo4j, netty, lxc

I am trying to get neo4j to run on a minimal install of Centos 7.2, neo4j installed through yum.

However it seems to start booting up, but fails, shuts down, then restarts in a continuous loop:

```
2017-07-18 03:06:34.731+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database health set to OK

017-07-18 03:06:35.140+0000 WARN [io.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil] Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: be:ac:2d:4b:9d:99:28:41

2017-07-18 03:06:35.226+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [1]:  Starting check pointing...
...
2017-07-18 03:06:35.335+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
```

ifconfig gives me:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.240  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f010:beff:fea8:314d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f2:10:be:a8:31:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 195385  bytes 316555671 (301.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 105586  bytes 7261323 (6.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7  bytes 391 (391.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 391 (391.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've tried setting dbms.connectors.default_listen_address to 0.0.0.0, the static ip, and commenting it out.

I feel like I might be missing a dependency or something that netty uses to get the MAC address, but the netty site claims no dependencies are required.

The last bit of info is that this is an lxc container, but I swear I have had a version of neo4j running in an lxc in the past.

Additionally this is being flagged as a warning, but it seems to be stopping the bootup.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution was to not use neo4j-admin and set the password using the web api.

This link shows a good example using curl:
http://430.io/change-neo4j-default-password-in-command-line/

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"password":"NEW PASSWORD"}' -u neo4j:neo4j http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

Answer (score 0):

After some work, I have discovered the reason.
The MAC address bit turned out to be a red herring.

The actual cause is using:

```
neo4j-admin set-initial-password mypass
```

Anytime I set the initial password this way, neo4j won't start properly.
Unfortunately I do need to figure out a way to set the initial password as this is part of an automated deployment.